# How to use "cmd" to bring up another "cmd" wiindow?

Tags: cmd, console, window

If I enter cmd, I enter the console window, but if I type cmd inside "cmd", it just start a sub shell of "cmd" inside it. My requirement is, in "cmd", I type one command, it brings up another windows "cmd" console.

How to do this?
Thanks

Comment: `cmd` isn't the terminal window, its the command line program that the user interacts with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `start cmd` should do it!
You can even call a batch file the same way, changing 'cmd' to your batch filename.

If `start cmd` doesn't work. You can try `start call cmd`.

Comment: Thanks, can I "start cmd" and let the new "cmd" run some program that I wanted? In other words, can I run "start cmd myprogram", I wish to get "myprogram" to run in a new cmd window. Thanks.

Comment: Yea sure. use the /k argument to send commands. For example: `start cmd /k ipconfig` will open up a new CMD window, running the ipconfig command. You can even chain commands. This example runs ipconfig and then pings google. `start cmd /k "ipconfig & ping google.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Just type the command as follows:

```
start
```

This will open a new command prompt.

Also

```
start cmd.exe
```

will do the same thing.

PS: The following method might also be helpful.

To open a command prompt in a particular directory in the file explorer, follow these steps:

> 1. Go to the required folder in the explorer
> 2. Click on the path toolbar. [Path toolbar in an explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzLp5.png)
> 3. Enter "cmd".[command prompt opened at the cwd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbp5p.png)

There you go! A cmd prompt opens up in the current working directory.